# SQL query in postgres database using left joins

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Okay so I've done some research and apparently, a left join can return more than 1 record based on the tables joined from the right.

my query is:

```
SELECT 
 ord.ID AS ord_id,
 oli.sfid AS oli_sfid,
 ord.HasMSISDN__c AS ord_HasMSISDN__c,
 ord.dealer_code__c AS ord_dealer_code__c, 
 ord.recordtypeid AS ord_recordtypeid,
 ord.order_number__c AS ord_order_number__c,
 ord.status AS ord_status,
 ord.opportunityid AS ord_opportunityid,
 ord.sfid AS ord_sfid,
 ord.cancelled_by__c AS ord_cancelled_by__c,
 ord.cancelled_on__c AS ord_cancelled_on__c,
 ord.created_by__c AS ord_created_by__c,
 ord.created_on__c AS ord_created_on__c,
 ord.docusign_email_address__c AS ord_docusign_email_address__c,
 ord.esignature_resent_to__c AS ord_esignature_resent_to__c, 
 ord.esignature_resent_by__c AS ord_esignature_resent_by__c,
 ord.esignature_resent_on__c AS ord_esignature_resent_on__c, 
 ord.pricebook2id AS ord_pricebook2id,
 cont.opportunity__c AS cont_opportunity__c,
 cont.sfid AS cont_sfid,
 opp.isclosed AS opp_isclosed,
 opp.sfid AS opp_sfid,
 opp.recordtypeid AS opp_recordtypeid,
 opp.pricebook2id AS opp_pricebook2id, 
 accban.sfid AS accban_sfid, 
 accban.ban__c AS accban_ban__c,
 usr.sfid AS usr_sfid  
 FROM fullsbxsalesforce.order ord
 LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.contract cont ON ord.contractid = cont.sfid
 LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.opportunity opp ON cont.opportunity__c = opp.sfid
 LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.user usr ON (ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_bd__c OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.Dealer_Code_Co_Sell__c OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.Rep_Dealer_Code__c OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_secondary__c) LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.account_ban_tax_id__c accban ON ord.ban_number__c = accban.ban__c 
 LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.orderitem oli ON ord.sfid = oli.orderid 
 WHERE ord.sfid = 'SPECIFIC ID'
```

Initially, I was under the impression that this would return 1 row. I am mistaken, it returns 3 rows because there are 3 different OLI's attached to the order. How can I ensure, or change my logic so that either, I am returned with a collection of OLI's in the same order or only return the first OLI so that I'm not dealing with 3 duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your rows returned in the same order, just add an `ORDER BY <col_name_list>` clause at the very end of your query.

Is an OLI a unique value?  Which table defines an OLI?

If you always want this query to always return one single row, just add a `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query.

If your query returns multiple OLI's and you only want one row per OLI, then you can use a window function:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
  -- Your initial query with new field added
  SELECT ...
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OLI_field_name ORDER BY <ordering_clause>) AS RowRank
  FROM ...
) src
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

This will return one row per `<OLI_field_name>`.

**Update**
If you want to just have one row per OLI and keep all the detailed info, use the window function method.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
   ord.ID AS ord_id,
   oli.sfid AS oli_sfid,
   ord.HasMSISDN__c AS ord_HasMSISDN__c,
   ord.dealer_code__c AS ord_dealer_code__c, 
   ord.recordtypeid AS ord_recordtypeid,
   ord.order_number__c AS ord_order_number__c,
   ord.status AS ord_status,
   ord.opportunityid AS ord_opportunityid,
   ord.sfid AS ord_sfid,
   ord.cancelled_by__c AS ord_cancelled_by__c,
   ord.cancelled_on__c AS ord_cancelled_on__c,
   ord.created_by__c AS ord_created_by__c,
   ord.created_on__c AS ord_created_on__c,
   ord.docusign_email_address__c AS ord_docusign_email_address__c,
   ord.esignature_resent_to__c AS ord_esignature_resent_to__c, 
   ord.esignature_resent_by__c AS ord_esignature_resent_by__c,
   ord.esignature_resent_on__c AS ord_esignature_resent_on__c, 
   ord.pricebook2id AS ord_pricebook2id,
   cont.opportunity__c AS cont_opportunity__c,
   cont.sfid AS cont_sfid,
   opp.isclosed AS opp_isclosed,
   opp.sfid AS opp_sfid,
   opp.recordtypeid AS opp_recordtypeid,
   opp.pricebook2id AS opp_pricebook2id, 
   accban.sfid AS accban_sfid, 
   accban.ban__c AS accban_ban__c,
   usr.sfid AS usr_sfid,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY oli.sfid ORDER BY <order_col>) AS RowRank -- Assigns a rank to each row with the same oli.sfid value
  FROM fullsbxsalesforce.order ord
  LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.contract cont ON ord.contractid = cont.sfid
  LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.opportunity opp ON cont.opportunity__c = opp.sfid
  LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.user usr ON (ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_bd__c OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.Dealer_Code_Co_Sell__c OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.Rep_Dealer_Code__c OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_secondary__c)
  LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.account_ban_tax_id__c accban ON ord.ban_number__c = accban.ban__c 
  LEFT JOIN fullsbxsalesforce.orderitem oli ON ord.sfid = oli.orderid 
  WHERE ord.sfid = 'SPECIFIC ID'
) src
WHERE RowRank = 1 -- Only get one row per oli.sfid value
```

This assumes that `oli.sfid` is the `OLI ID`

Just change the outer `SELECT *` to return all the fields except `RowRank`.  Also, modify the `<order_col>` value to determine which row you want to return for each `oli.sfid`.

Comment: this is a batch process so it needs to return more than 1 row, I removed a lot of the logic in order to simplify the query.  an oli is an order item, each order should/can have multiple oli's, but I only need the first one to ensure that the olis have already been built or in order to know if none exist so that I can build them

Comment: OK.  Then you should use the Window function method I suggested.  It's similar to doing a DISTINCT/GROUP BY, except it retains the detailed rows.  See updated answer shortly.

Comment: what do you mean by retains the detailed rows?

Comment: When you do a normal aggregate function, it summarizes (i.e. adds up, gets the average) all the row data.  The only values you get returned are the fields specified in `GROUP BY` and the aggregates.  With the window function, you can do similar operations, but you can keep all the detailed data (i.e. additional columns not specified in the `GROUP BY`)

Answer (score 1):

Not very nice, but you can set a subquery as a table in your `FROM` clause instead of doing the left join with oli:

```
, (select * from fullsbxsalesforce.orderitem WHERE ord.sfid = orderid limit 1) oli
```

Comment: how will this return? will this return a collection of olis? Currently I'm creating a json by putting json.put("fieldname", resultset.get("queryfieldname");

Answer (score 1):

I would question whether or not you only want one record? I see two potential answers:

## 1. You want all the Order Items

That you are selecting from the `OrderItems` table implies you want records from there. If three records match your results, then it seems illogical that you would want to arbitrarily ignore some?

(I've seen this, and done it, but it is indicative of a problem)

## 2. You don't want Order Items at all

This seems more likely, based on your willingness to just discard the data.

That you are willing to just discard the data all together would imply that you don't actually want it in the first place. If you don't want it, just don't include the table at all.

## Conclusion

Looking at your query I am guessing you are in case #2. The issue more likely that you have included a table unnecessarily.

Where you say `oli.sfid AS oli_sfid`, did you mean to get the `sfid` of the order? If so, you no longer need the join on `OrderItems`.

If after reading all of that, you are still sure you want just one, totally arbitrary, item from the order, `order by` and `limit` (as suggested by others) are the solution.

## 3. Edit: A third scenario

After reading a comment by the OP: If all that is being attempted to verify that `OrderItems` exist, aggregation may be another way to go:

```
SELECT ord.ID AS ord_id,
       count(*) AS oli_count,
       ord.HasMSISDN__c AS ord_HasMSISDN__c,
       ...
       accban.ban__c AS accban_ban__c,
       usr.sfid AS usr_sfid  
FROM   order ord
       ...
       LEFT JOIN orderitem oli ON ord.sfid = oli.orderid 
WHERE  ord.sfid = 'SPECIFIC ID'
GROUP BY
       ord.ID,
       ord.HasMSISDN__c,
       ...
       accban.ban__c,
       usr.sfid
```

Though in this case, the `group by` would be difficult and painful to maintain.

If the objective is to ignore Orders that do not have items associated with them, then you don't want a `left join`, you want an `inner join`:

```
SELECT ord.ID AS ord_id,
       ...
       oli.sfid AS oli_sfid,
       usr.sfid AS usr_sfid  
FROM   fullsbxsalesforce.order ord
       INNER JOIN orderitem oli ON ord.sfid = oli.orderid 
       LEFT JOIN contract cont ON ord.contractid = cont.sfid
       LEFT JOIN opportunity opp ON cont.opportunity__c = opp.sfid
       LEFT JOIN user usr ON ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_bd__c 
                             OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.Dealer_Code_Co_Sell__c 
                             OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.Rep_Dealer_Code__c 
                             OR ord.dealer_code__c = usr.dealer_code_secondary__c
       LEFT JOIN account_ban_tax_id__c accban ON ord.ban_number__c = accban.ban__c 
 WHERE ord.sfid = 'SPECIFIC ID'
```

Note the change of position of `orderitem` in the table sequence.

Comment: So unfortunately, Kindof the data doesn't matter. We create the order items by code only, so if the order items have been created, I only need to verify that 1 exists, I don't even need to check if it's correct, only that it exists.. If 1 exists then they have been created already, if none exist then I need to create them.

Comment: I added my third scenario at the same time you were leaving the comment. I'm not sure if it applies now.

Comment: Wait! Are you specifically looking for orders that don't have orderitems?